# How to include .so files in Android studio Library Module?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I've been trying to include .so files in a library module using android studio, but unable to to do so and getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.

I've also unzipped and checked the apk generated from App Module (which depends upon my library module containing .so files), it does contains all the required .so files in it, but still i get the **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError**

I've also tried all the other solutions present on existing threads like converting .so files to jar and then adding as dependency, adding .so files to jniLibs folder, converting library module to jar and adding jar dependency to app-module etc but no result?

p.s I'm using android studio 2.0 with gradle plugin version 2.0

Comment: Have you tried using a build.gradle or Android.mk file to add the .so files as dependencies to your project?

Comment: Are you include those .so files to use by your JNI code, or just to run java library?

Comment: @V-master just including .so files as dependency to run the java library

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following project structure. It worked for me with nothing the gradle.

```
  > project/
      libs/
        fm.jar, etc. // <-- .jar files go here
      src/
        main/
          java/
            (your java files)
          jniLibs/
            arm64-v8a/
              libopus.so, etc. // <-- .so files for ARM 64-bit go here
            armeabi-v7a/
              libopus.so, etc. // <-- .so files for ARM 32-bit go here
            x86/
              libopus.so, etc. // <-- .so files for Intel 32-bit go here
          res/
            (your drawables/layouts/values)
```